# prevent class components from re-rendering child functional components after state array is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm facing an issue in my react application. I noticed when I check out my *console.logs* I am seeing messages that my 3 child (functional) components are getting re-rendered from the Home.js class components.

In my setup I placed 3 functional components "FooComponent.js" which I am using in my Home.js component. As a side note in Home.js I am also dispatching an action to ping for new values every 100ms. See below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import FooComponent from './FooComponent'

class Home extends Component {
    static displayName = Home.name;
    
    componentDidMount() {

        this.timerID = setInterval(() => {
            this.props.getValues();
        }, 100);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timerID);
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextState) {
        
        console.log('Home - shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle');

        return false;
    }

    render() {

        return (

            <div className="container">
                <h1>Timers</h1>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm">
                        <FooComponent name={{ id: '001', userName: 'Alvin', value: 0 }} />
                        <FooComponent name={{ id: '002', userName: 'Simon', value: 0 }} />
                        <FooComponent name={{ id: '003', userName: 'Theodore', value: 0 }} />
                    </div>
                </div>              
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        nodes: state.users
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        getValues: () => dispatch({ type: 'getValues' })
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

I have my FooComponent set up as follows:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const FooComponent = (props) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const users = useSelector(state => state.users);
    
    const getLatestUserValue = () => {
        var matched = users.find(function (element1) {
            return (element1.id === props.name.id);
        });

        let value = props.name.value;

        if (matched !== undefined) {
            value = matched.value
        }
        return <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{value}</h6>;
    }

    // renders component
    function componentMount() {
        dispatch({ type: 'addUser', userInfo: { id: props.name.id, subName: props.name.userName, value: props.name.value } });
    }

    // leaves the component
    function componentUnmount() {

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        componentMount();
        return () => {
            componentUnmount();
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="card shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
            <div className="card-header">
                <h5>User Id: {props.name.id}, Name: {props.name.userName}</h5>
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">
                {getLatestUserValue()}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default FooComponent;
```

As you can see I'm also using redux. This is something I need to use in order to manage my state across many components that will need to access it.

In my redux "store" I am using a reducer method to handle my incoming dispatches:

```
const simulationModelNodeReducer = (state = { nodes: [] }, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {      
        //..other cases
        case 'getValues':
            
            let matchedUsers = [];
            
            //..logic to retrieve list of users that got updated
            //.. matchedUsers gets populated here if the incoming users from the server
            // ..match the users that state has in its users array
            
            if (matchedUsers.length > 0) {
                // 1. Make a shallow copy of the items
                let users = [...state.users];

                for (var i = 0; i < matchedUsers.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < users.length; j++) {
                        // 2. Make a shallow copy of the item you want to mutate
                        let user = { ...users[j] };
                        if (user.uniqueName === matchedUsers[i].uniqueName &&
                            user.subName === matchedUsers[i].subName) {
                            // 3. Replace the property you're intested in
                            user.value = matchedUsers[i].value;
                            // 4. Put it back into our array. N.B. we *are* mutating the array here, but that's why we made a copy first
                            users[i] = user;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return {
                    ...state,
                    users: users
                }
            }
            
            break;      
    }
    return state;
};
```

Its in this store (UserStore.js) where the spamming happens. As soon as I return the new users array object, I update the state but every component then gets called to render. Even if it was only one user getting updated.

I tried a number of tutorials that sort of faced my problem:

https://linguinecode.com/post/how-to-avoid-multiple-re-renders-in-react-shouldcomponentupdate

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-shouldcomponentupdate-method/

And I have even used "memo" in my FooComponent class and even tried creatinga  sub component of the part that only renders the value section but all of my three components keep getting called every time my state updates.

Can anyone help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to wrap your functional component in React.memo and pass a comparator function (to check whether the previous prop is the same as the new one) since you are passing an object and what memo does by default is a shallow comparison

Comment: @ludwiguer I seem to remember trying out React.memo...if its not trouble could you write out that function and where might I put that? One thing I failed to mention is that in my Home.js where I instantiate FooComponent I am only passing then the id, name and initial value. Forevermore the values I get in props after that will always be 0.

Comment: export default React.memo(FooComponent, (prevProps, nextProps) => { /* return true if the objects are equal here*/ })

Comment: @ludwiguer I managed to get it to work thank you so much. I will be posting what I had to do in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The default rendering model of React is to always rerender all children once a parent component is updated. That is usually a fast thing and does not matter at all, unless you are rerendering a component at the root of your application multiple times per second.

You *can* work around this with `React.memo`, but using that has it's own cost - and littering it over your code base is probably more expensive to not using it at all and just having the rerenders.

You should only use optimizations like that after you have benchmarked & measured your components and have come to the conclusion that you need to avoid triggering a specific component rerendering for performance reasons. Otherwise, just let it rerender.

Comment: after I benchmarked I noticed that just my 3 child components re-rendered about 214 times in 2 seconds even if their values haven't changed.

Comment: Then you should probably look into why your parent component rerenders that often.